# Redirect after Response has been written in Wicket 7.10

Tags: response, wicket, wicket-7

We having a specific problem in using Wicket 7.10, creating an Ajax-Response with multiple  entries.

In our application, we are using `onRequestHandlerResolved` to do some initialization stuff and `onRequestHandlerExecuted` to save changes done on our data during `requestHandlerExecutor.execute()`.
For this purpose, we have created an own `AbstractRequestCycleListener` which overwrites both methods and calls our specific code.

RequestCycle:

```
private void execute(IRequestHandler handler)
{
  try
  {
    listeners.onRequestHandlerResolved(this, handler);
    requestHandlerExecutor.execute(handler);
    listeners.onRequestHandlerExecuted(this, handler);
  }
  catch (RuntimeException e)
  {
  }
}
```

Our problem is, that an Exception thrown in `onRequestHandlerExecuted` after `requestHandlerExecutor.execute()` has already created an ajax-response creates an invalid response:

```
Wicket.Ajax:  Wicket.Ajax.Call.failure: Error while parsing response: Error: Invalid XML: 
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<ajax-response>
  <!-- Result of requestHandlerExecutor.execute()  -->
</ajax-response>
<ajax-response>
  <!—Redirect to specific Exception Page, result of onRequestHandlerExecuted -->
  <redirect>
    <![CDATA[./wicket/bookmarkable/our.package.ExceptionPage?locale=en]]>
  </redirect>
</ajax-response>
```

To solve our problem, we tried to clear the existing Response during Exception in `onRequestHandlerExecuted` (`RequestCycle.get().getResponse().reset()`), but we are not able to clear the Response, created in `requestHandlerExecutor.execute()`, because Wicket uses `HeaderBufferingWebResponse` by default which did not allow to reset already created Response in encapsulated `ServletWebResponse`. Calling reset in `HeaderBufferingWebResponse` instead throws an `IllegalStateException`.

We think that the problem came from `ServletWebResponse` which simply adds multiple ajax-response entries to the `HttpServletResponse` which results in the mentioned, invalid XML.

ServletWebResponse:

```
@Override
public void sendRedirect(String url)
{
 try
 {
  if (webRequest.isAjax())
  {
   /*
    * usually the Ajax-Location header is enough and we do not need to the redirect url
    * into the response, but sometimes the response is processed via an iframe (eg
    * using multipart ajax handling) and the headers are not available because XHR is
    * not used and that is the only way javascript has access to response headers.
    */
   httpServletResponse.getWriter().write(
    "<ajax-response><redirect><![CDATA[" + url + "]]></redirect></ajax-response>");
  }
  else { }
 }
 catch (IOException e) {  }
}
```

How we could handle the problem when throwing an Exception in `onRequestHandlerExecuted`? And how is it possible, that code run after `requestHandlerExecutor.execute()`, redirects correctly to an Exception page?
How we can run specific code, after the request has been processed, is there maybe another way instead of overwriting `onRequestHandlerExecuted`?

Comment: I have already answered you on the mailing list two days ago.

Comment: Sorry, i did not recognize your answer in the mailing list.

Answer (score 0):

For each Ajax request Wicket executes two request handlers:

- ListenerInterfaceRequestHandler
- AjaxRequestHandler

I assume your #onRequestHandlerExecuted is failing after the second one. This might be too late since the response is already generated and written.

You could check:

- why does your listener fail *after* anything else has happened already?
- what do you want your application to do when your listener fails?
- can't the listener fail after the first handler already? why wait any longer?